# Half-wave rectifier with resistor and inductor load

Tags: power-electronics, rectifier

I am studying a half-wave rectifier with a resistor and inductor load.

It is commonly taught that the diode conducts when it is forward biased-  that is, the anode voltage is greater than the cathode voltage. The half-wave rectifier with a resistor and inductor seems to violate this.

Why does the diode continue to conduct even when the source is in the negative half cycle?

[image]

Comment: That's because you have an inductor in the load - the diode still only conducts when it's anode is at greater voltage than the cathode.

Comment: @Kevin White I understand that the inductor delays the current and releases it when the voltage drops, what I don't understand is if the voltage across the anode is negative, because the diode continues to conduct while the inductor discharges?

Comment: That's because when the inductor discharges it develops a votlage across it that causes  the voltgae at the cathode of the diode to be even more more negative than at the anode.

Answer (score 3):

The diode conducts whenever the anode voltage is greater than the cathode voltage (ideally).

In this case the anode voltage is zero, but the cathode voltage is less than zero so the diode continues to conduct.

Unfortunately, this image does not explicitly show the reference ground, which is the (-) terminal of Vs.

[image]

Comment: Because the voltage is zero at the anode? Is it not assumed that the anode is seeing the source? If the voltage at the anode is negative, the voltage at the cathode should be negative and much lower than the voltage at the anode so that the diode continued conducting right?

Comment: At the zero crossing of the source, the voltage at the anode is zero (of course, since they're connected together). The voltage at the cathode at the zero crossing is less than zero. The reason for that is that the inductor voltage vL will change to attempt to keep the current through the diode flowing.

Answer (score 0):

See in the pictures the diode voltage where it is "positive" ... That mean generator voltage is higher then inductor voltage at these moments because of the behavior of inductor.

For illustrating what has been pointed above, here are some pictures comparing "with diode" or "no diode". (SEO).

I will point out also facts that are useful in powers systems.

1- transient starting ... Starting behavior is quasi the same for currents.

When phase generator is  0°, peak current TWO times (short transient ?), then "steady state" at normal current.

When phase generator is 90°, immediately "steady state".

2- Peak current with diode will be TWO times the current in the circuit without a diode in "steady state". So, choose fuse accordingly, especially when there can be a "high inductive short" when a diode is present.

Voltage generator begins at phase 0°.

[image]

Voltage generator begins at phase 90°

No transient. "Immediately" steady state.

[image]